react-quill not working in Nextjs 15 and react 19
I’m using React 19 with Next.js 15, and I’m facing issues with react-quill. The editor component fails to load, causing errors related to incompatible React versions.
Steps tried:

Installed react-quill (v2.0.0).
Attempted dynamic imports and custom configurations, but the error persists.
Tried using different versions of react-quill without success.

This is error message: TypeError: react_dom_1.default.findDOMNode is not a function
I'm looking for solutions and know about react quill.

I'd have solved this problem just minutes ago. I'm looking to solve it and I could.
I just updated the new version of React Quill, I knew through browsing about this problem.
react-quill-new
Installed and removed the previous one. I deleted the previous version codes and updated them.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
